# Loop or Array BUT Also Remove 1 Object Out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, refactoring

I would like to refactor this long audio-playing script to make it more — i didn’t involved in that >:( — by using an array.

```
   <script>
   /* ... */
   /* Used by other trigger */

   var m1 = $(".bgm-one")[0];
   var m2 = $(".bgm-two")[0];
   var m3 = $(".bgm-three")[0];
   var m4 = $(".bgm-four")[0];
   var m5 = $(".bgm-five")[0];
   var m6 = $(".bgm-six")[0];
   var m7 = $(".bgm-seven")[0];
   var m8 = $(".bgm-eight")[0];
   var m9 = $(".bgm-nine")[0];
   var m10 = $(".bgm-ten")[0];
   var m11 = $(".bgm-eleven")[0];
   var m12 = $(".bgm-twelve")[0];
   var playing = true;

   if (setBGM == "bgm1"){
   m2.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m2.pause()}, 1450);
   m3.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m3.pause()}, 1450);
   m4.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m4.pause()}, 1450);
   m5.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m5.pause()}, 1450);
   m6.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m6.pause()}, 1450);
   m7.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m7.pause()}, 1450);
   m8.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m8.pause()}, 1450);
   m9.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m9.pause()}, 1450);
   m10.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m10.pause()}, 1450);
   m11.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m11.pause()}, 1450);
   m12.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m12.pause()}, 1450);

   m1.addEventListener("ended", function(){this.currentTime = 0;if (playing){this.play();}}, false);

   setTimeout(function(){
   m1.animate({volume: 0.1}, 1450);
   m1.play();
   }, 1450);

   setTimeout(function(){
   m1.animate({volume: 1}, 1500);
   }, 1450);
   }

   if (setBGM == "bgm2"){
   m1.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m1.pause()}, 1450);
   m3.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m3.pause()}, 1450);
   m4.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m4.pause()}, 1450);
   m5.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m5.pause()}, 1450);
   m6.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m6.pause()}, 1450);
   m7.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m7.pause()}, 1450);
   m8.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m8.pause()}, 1450);
   m9.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m9.pause()}, 1450);
   m10.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m10.pause()}, 1450);
   m11.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m11.pause()}, 1450);
   m12.animate({volume: 0}, 1400);setTimeout(function(){m12.pause()}, 1450);

   m2.addEventListener("ended", function(){this.currentTime = 0;if (playing){this.play();}}, false);

   setTimeout(function(){
   m2.animate({volume: 0.1}, 1450);
   m2.play();
   }, 1450);

   setTimeout(function(){
   m2.animate({volume: 1}, 1500);
   }, 1450);
   }

   /* ... And the rest of the list that will be too long to include; like "if (setBGM == "bgm3")," "if (setBGM == "bgm4")"... */
   </script>
```

> 

Above there are 12 different variable declarations and method calls, and it maybe can be converted into Array-like code, but how to exclude one object from each line? Like in line of m1, then it exclude var m1...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by "Like to exclude one object out of this twelve ones?"?

Comment: This was the solution that i’ve got from previously deleted question about how to play background music and also sfx but each bgm doesn’t get crossed.

Comment: Oh, sorry i didn’t read a somebody is already texting. I don’t know how to illustrate it, but i see in each "if (setBGM == bgm...)" the bgm does get excluded from the list of animate() just right below it. The real question was just how can i trim it all short – but the site said that it is not a good question.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and see if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). A for loop lets you iterate through arrays and can greatly shorten the code you have.

https://jsfiddle.net/7wsgtkLj/12/

Here's a start to refactoring (I changed the first half, so see if you can fix the rest):

```
let musicEls = [];
const numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"];
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  musicEls.push($(".bgm-" + numbers[i])[0]);
}
var playing = true;

if (setBGM == "bgm1"){
  for (int i = 0; i < musicEls.length; i++) {
    musicEls[i].animate({volume: 0}, 1400);
    setTimeout(function(){m2.pause()}, 1450);

  }
...
```

I highly suggest you also read up on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). The array has a `.push()` method which is used in the code above.